# abcpdf page-break-before not working on last items in the list

Tags: abcpdf

Documentation from abcpdf, http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/3-concepts/g-htmlrender.htm, says that the html element below will cause a page break. It does but for the last page as you can see in the screen shot it doesnt.  HTML passes validation, and the breaks are there so is this a bug?

```
<div style="page-break-before: always">&nbsp;</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your html which being rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be by design, so no fix for it.